# Mac Big Sur home folder permissions: Read-only file system when renaming files

Tags: macos, terminal, permission, big-sur, sip

**UPDATE #2**

I was able to successfully rename the files using sed:

```
for f in *.Rdat; do mv $f $(echo $f | sed "s/PCC-//"); done
```

**UPDATE**
I discovered I can rename individual files:

```
mv 'PCC-ASR-L.Rdat' 'ASR-L.Rdat'
```

So evidently the problem occurs only when trying to batch rename in a `for loop`. I would still like to understand why.

**ORIGINAL POST**

After upgrading to `Big Sur` from `Catalina`, I tried to use the terminal to **rename some files** in a subfolder of my `Home` folder. I had created and used the subfolder before upgrading. Specifically, I tried renaming a group of `Rdat` files using a `bash for loop`. I could do this under Catalina, **but now I get an error**. Here, I am trying to replace 'PCC-' in each file name with an empty string (i.e. `''`):

```
for f in *.Rdat; do mv $f ${f/PCC-//}; done
```

This yields an error for every file, like this (for file `PCC-ASR-H.Rdat`):

```
mv: /ASR-H.Rdat: Read-only file system
```

This seems strange because as owner of the folder I have `write permissions`:

```
drwxr-xr-x    8 mike  staff   256 Nov 21 15:04 Rdatafiles
```

And I have `write permissions` for the files in the folder (example):

```
-rw-rw-r--@ 1 mike  staff  10926 Dec  4 18:26 PCC-ASR-H.Rdat
```

I tried disabling `SIP` in `Recovery Mode`:

```
csrutil disable
```

But the problem remains. **Is it possible to make subfolders of the home folder writeable under `Big Sur`?** Are there some additional changes I need to make to the system (i.e. `permissions`) to enable write access? Or do I now need to move my work files out of `Home` and into, say, `Home/Documents`, to avoid this issue?

Comment: The problem is the double forward-slash in `${f/PCC-//}`. Unlike a `sed` substitution pattern, there's no `/` at the end of the replacement pattern (it's terminated by `}`), so the extra `/` is taken as the replacement string. This turns e.g. "PCC-ASR-L.Rdat" into "/ASR-L.Rdat", which (because of the "/") is at the root of the filesystem... which is read-only. Note: using `set -x` before the command will show what's going on (i.e. what the command looks like *after* substitutions are performed) in cases like this.

Comment: wow awesome explanation @GordonDavisson! If you can make this an answer I will select it as the correct one

Comment: Use Finder's rename function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the double forward-slash in `${f/PCC-//}`. Unlike a sed substitution pattern, there's no `/` at the end of the replacement pattern (it's terminated by `}`), so the extra `/` is taken as the replacement string. This turns e.g. "PCC-ASR-L.Rdat" into "/ASR-L.Rdat", which (because of the "/") is at the root of the filesystem... which is read-only.

When I'm doing things like batch renames, I also often don't get everything right on the first try, so I tend to do a dry run with `echo` in front of the `mv` (or `cp` or `rm` or...) command first, so I can see what's going to happen before actually running it. I also *strongly* recommend using `mv -i` or `mv -f`, so if there's any sort of naming conflict it won't just silently and irreversibly overwrite files. Also, putting double-quotes around variable references is a good idea, in case any filenames contain weird characters.

So my dry run would look something like this:

```
for f in *.Rdat; do echo mv -i "$f" "${f/PCC-/}"; done
```

...and if that looked right, I'd hit up-arrow to get it back, delete the "echo", and re-run it for real.

If you need to troubleshoot in even more detail, using set -x before the command will show what the shell thinks is going on (i.e. what the command looks like after substitutions are performed) in cases like this.